# Resampling pandas Dataframe keeping other columns

Tags: pandas

I'm facing a problem with a pandas dataframe. Actually my Dataframe contains 3 columns: `DATE_TIME`, `SITE_NB`, `VALUE`.
For some `SITE_NB` there are missing rows. For example:

```
DATE_TIME;SITE_NB; VALUE

2011-01-03 01:00; 1; 10.7

2011-01-03 04:00; 1; 3.2

2011-01-03 05:00; 1; -2.1
```

So here, rows for `2011-01-03 00:00`, `2011-01-03 02:00` and `2011-01-03 03:00` are missing. What I want is add these rows with the same `SITE_NB (=1)` and with `VALUE (=NaN)`

I want to do the same for all different `SITE_NB` in my dataframe. So for each `SITE_NB`, add missing rows based on `DATE_TIME` with a frequency of 1 Hour, and putting `NaN` in `VALUE` for freshly added rows.

I tried resampling but did not get the right output...

Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add missing indices, use:

```
full_idx = pd.date_range(start='<start_date>', end='<end_date>', freq='H')

df.reindex(full_idx)
```

That will put NaN's in SITE_NB and VALUE columns.

If each dataframe has only one value of SITE_NB, you can use:

```
df['SITE_NB'].fillna(df['SITE_NB'].unique()[0], inplace=True)
```

which replaces all NaN's with the first non-null values in the column.

---

If you actually have one dataframe with multiple SITE_NB values, could you please show what that looks like? Are the time indices overlapping in some cases or not?

Also, this answer might work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275540/pandas-reindex-dates-in-groupby

Comment: Thank you Nemanja Radojković ! creating a new index and reindexing the dataframe solved my issue!

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)